# Getting the position of an item inside a List

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist, android-notifications

I have a list with different songs in them. When the user selects one song from the list, a new activity opens with play/pause controls. If the user clicks the Play button, a notification is generated.

In that notification it has to show the title, the artist name and the thumbnail of the song.
But my problem is I can't get the position of the users selected item. Right now I set the position to some integer so when the user selects an item from the list, for example the third item, it still shows the information about the first item in the list...Because I set the position=0.

How can I get the position the user selected?

**MainActivity**

```
public List<Song> lstSongs;
int position = 0;
boolean isPlaying = false;


@Override
public void onTrackPlay() {

    CreateNotification.createNotification(MainActivity.this, lstSongs.get(position),
            R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp, position, lstSongs.size()-1);
    play_fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp);
    tv_title.setText(lstSongs.get(position).getTitle());
    tv_artist.setText(lstSongs.get(position).getArtist());

    isPlaying = true;

}
```

**DataSource**

```
 public class DataSource {
        public static List<Song> getMusic(){

        List<Song> lstSongs = new ArrayList<>();
        lstSongs.add(new Song("Title1","Artist1", R.drawable.cover1,"Category Name 1"));
        lstSongs.add(new Song("Title2","Artist2",R.drawable.cover2,"Category Name 2"));
        lstSongs.add(new Song("Title3","Artist3",R.drawable.cover3,"Category Name 3"));
        lstSongs.add(new Song("Title4","Artist4",R.drawable.cover4,"Category Name 4"));
        lstSongs.add(new Song("Title5","Artist5",R.drawable.cover5,"Category Name 5"));
        lstSongs.add(new Song("Title6","Artist6",R.drawable.cover6,"Category Name 6"));
        lstSongs.add(new Song("Title7","Artist7",R.drawable.cover7,"Category Name 7"));

        return lstSongs; 
}
```

Comment: Create an Adapter class where you get the position and then pass this position to Activity  or whatever you want

Comment: I'm a beginner, can you please elaborate?

Comment: here is the sample project you can take a look: https://github.com/Marsad-Ch/testappp.git

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome